# Need to match multiple pattern in the same line - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to match multiple pattern in the same line. For example, in this file:

```
Hello, Chester [McAllister;Scientist] lives in Boston [Massachusetts;USA;Fenway Park] # McAllister works in USA
I'm now working in New-York [NYC;USA] # I work in USA
...
```

First, I want to match every string into the brackets knowing that it is possible to have more than 1 pattern and also that we can have 1 to *n* strings into the brackets always separated by a semicolon.

Finally, for each line i need to compare the values to the string located after the `#`. For example in the first sentence, i want to compare:

```
[McAllister;Scientist] & [Massachusetts;USA;Fenway Park] TO "McAllister works in USA"
```

Comment: you mean this `\[[^;\n]*(?:;[^;\n]*)+\]` http://regex101.com/r/uT5cC0/2'

Comment: What are you trying to do, get them into an array ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've tried this `if($sentence =~ /(\[[^;]*(?:;[^;]*)+\])/g){ print $1."\n"; }` but for the first line the result is: `[McAllister;Scientist] lives in Boston [Massachusetts;USA;Fenway Park]`

Comment: @sln Why not. Finally, i need to compare each value separated by a semicolon to a string. I edit the answer to be clearer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The tidiest way is probably to use a regex to find all the embedded sequences delimited by square brackets, and then use `map` with `split` to separate those sequences into terms.

This program demonstrates.

Note that I have assumed that all of the data in the file has been read into a single scalar variable. You can alter this to process a single line at a time, but only if the bracketed subsequences are never split across multiple lines

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = <<END_TEXT;
Hello, Chester [McAllister;Scientist] lives in Boston [Massachusetts;USA;Fenway Park] # McAllister works in USA
I'm now working in New-York [NYC;USA] # I work in USA
END_TEXT

my @data = map [ split /;/ ], $s =~ / \[ ( [^\[\]]+ ) \] /xg;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;
```

**output**

```
[
  ["McAllister", "Scientist"],
  ["Massachusetts", "USA", "Fenway Park"],
  ["NYC", "USA"],
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

This is also gives what you expect.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open('new',"file.txt");
my @z =map{m/\[[\w;\s]+\]/g} <new>;
print "$_ ,",foreach(@z);
```

You actually need match the words separated by the `;` within the `[]`.